# How can I get more decimals from an AWK substr division

Tags: awk, floating-point

On OpenWRT, I have the following "expression" in a shell script:

`gps2="$(echo -e "$gps" |awk -F , '/\,/ {print "&lat="(substr($2,0,2) + (substr($2,3) / 60.0)) "&lon=" (substr($4,0,3) + (substr($4,4) / 60.0)) ; fflush();}' | head -1 )"`

$gps contains the following:
`+CGPSINFO,3752.036737,N,02344.725959,E,120301,125950.0,50.5,0.0,32.0`

The result of $gps2 is this:
`&lat=37.8673&lon=23.7454`

as you can see, i only have 4 decimals from `(substr($2,3) / 60.0) and (substr($4,4) / 60.0)`
How can I get more decimals?
`lat= 52.036737 / 60 = 0.86727895 + 37 = 37.86727895 and not 37.8673` as per my result.

Any help Very much appreciated.

Thank you  in advance.

DD

Comment: I don't see how that works as `$2` from `$gps` is `N` and `$4` is `E`. Are you sure you have the right code and data?

Comment: sorry... you are right!!! the line before is gps="$(grep '+CGPSINFO,' /tmp/gpsdata)"!  /tmp/gpsdata has that full line!

Comment: actually, echo on $gps is giving me this:     +CGPSINFO,3752.036552,N,02344.725664,E,120301,134820.0,50.0,0.0,32.0     I have amended the line in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo '3752.036737' | awk '{print "&lat="(substr($1,0,2) + (substr($1,3) / 60.0))}' CONVFMT='%.6f'
&lat=37.867279
```

Comment: NAILED IT!!!  
gps2="$(echo -e "$gps" |awk -F , '/\,/ {print "&lat="(substr($2,0,2) + (substr($2,3) / 60.0)) "&lon=" (substr($4,0,3) + (substr($4,4) / 60.0)) ; fflush();}'  CONVFMT='%.8f'| head -1 )"
gives:
&lat=37.86738583&lon=23.74548098

THANK YOU!!!!!!